# Prefetch Text Layout in RecyclerView, cannot resolve method setTextFuture

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, prefetch

I'm trying to add Prefetch Text Layout to my `reyclerview` as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXqwRhjd7b4&feature=youtu.be) and [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/prefetch-text-layout-in-recyclerview-4acf9103f438).  Weirdly, it is only working on a my custom `TextView` and not with standard `TextViews`.  For my standard TextView, I get `Cannot resolve method setTextFuture` error.

Also to add, everything was working fine before.  the standard `setText` method worked for either custom or regular `TextView`.  I have a total of four (4) TextViews, and all return the same error.  I cast one as a custom TextView (even though it wasn't) and the error went away.

Here's my cleaned up code.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder rvh, int position){
    rvh.setMtbCard(listFiltered_main.get(position));
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tv_name;
    public LengthTextView tv_length;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView, final int viewType){
        super(itemView);

        tv_name =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
        tv_length =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_length);

    public void setMtbCard(final TrailsObject trailsObject) {

        //not working... getting "Cannot resolve method setTextFuture" error
        tv_name.setTextFuture(PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture(
                trailsObject.getName_diff(),
                tv_name.getTextMetricsParamsCompat(),
                null)
        );

        //seemingly works fine
        tv_length.setTextFuture(PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture(
                trailsObject.getLength_mi(),
                tv_length.getTextMetricsParamsCompat(),
                null)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AppCompatTextView` instead of `TextView`

XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_id"
    />
```

In Adapter

```
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;

public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder rvh, int position){
    rvh.tv.setTextFuture(PrecomputedTextCompat.getTextFuture(
            string_text,
            tv.getTextMetricsParamsCompat(),
            null) //or your executor
    );
}

public class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public final AppCompatTextView tv;

    public RecyclerViewHolder(final View itemView, final int viewType){
        super(itemView);

        tv =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);


         //......
    }
}
```